# nav-pills stretching full width, does not work using %

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a small app and have now to deal with the front end part of it. I am using bootstrap for it. For the navbar part, I am using `nav-pills` navbar, and I want it stretched to 100%. My navbar code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-static-top" >
    <div class="navbar-inner">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" >


                    <li ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the css part:

```
.nav-pills{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;

}
.nav-pills > li { 
  float: left;

}
```

Now if i change the 100% in nav-pills to say `1366px`, it works. But when I scale it to 100%, the navbar is not stretched. I tried giving the width of `.nav-pills > li` to  25%, trying with just 4 tabs. That also gives the perfect result. But since the number of tabs vary from page to page, I don't want to fix the size of the `.nav-pills > li` class. I want to stretch the navbar to full width. What is that I should do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mEjLV/ - tell me what's wrong here, it stretches vertically just fine...

Comment: @bardzusny: But the tabs are all to the left. I want them equally scaled.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that with css alone. Width of li elements...it has to be something. Either percentage - which will vary depending on number of < li > if you want to make sure sum of their widths is 100%...and other options (px!) are even less flexible.

tl;dr: You won't do that without js. Unless you know how many li elements you will have. Which you don't...

Comment: is this a better representation of what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/eDtsV/1/

Comment: Will this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/eDtsV/2/  - You just need to expand the lower right 'output' window in order to see exactly what a medium/large screen would show. And you can do this with CSS alone... Bootstrap has a class named "nav-justified" specifically for this.

Comment: @bardzusny, you did not add the bootstrap files to your JSFiddle.. how can you tell whether it stretches fine or not?

Comment: Of course I took it as generic css question, mea culpa. Once and never again, sorry!

Comment: No Worries @bardzusny, I apologize for coming off harsh! :(

Comment: I hate it when people say "this isn't possible with CSS" when it is entirely possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has a [`nav-justified`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) class that does exactly what you want (at screens wider than 768px, on smaller screens the nav links are stacked).

Just add it to your `.nav` like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/73rNv/)**

Comment: Nice, this was pretty much the same thing I posted in the comments! +1 for actually putting it up.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I missed your comment, I probably would've left the question alone if I had seen it. Apologies.

Comment: Don't even sweat it, you did it all on your own! :)

Answer (score 0):

`nav-pills nav-justified` items not width fixed.
For this case:
**HTML**

```
<div class="gridProducts_box">
    <ul class="nav nav-pill">
        <li class="gridProducts_box__items">
            <a href="#tab-one" data-toggle="tab" class="btnFilter">One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gridProducts_box__items">
            <a href="#tab-two" data-toggle="tab" class="btnFilter">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gridProducts_box__items">
            <a href="#tab-three" data-toggle="tab" class="btnFilter">Three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gridProducts_box__items">
            <a href="#tab-four" data-toggle="tab" class="btnFilter">Four</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gridProducts_box__items">
            <a href="#tab-five" data-toggle="tab" class="btnFilter">Five</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* nav tabs fixed wodth */
.gridProducts_box > ul.nav.nav-pills {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.gridProducts_box > ul.nav.nav-pills > li {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
}

    .gridProducts_box > ul.nav.nav-pills > li > a {
        text-align: center;
    }

.gridProducts_box__items {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiAfzal/cLp1cguc/)